# Get a thread by its name for checking IsAlive Status

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am currently using various threads in my application and each of those threads have a distinct name. I wanted to know if there is a way through which I could determine if that thread is running or not using the IsAlive Property. I did find some data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182917/get-a-thread-by-its-name). But I could not figure it out.

Comment: What was the confusion? The answers in that SO answer tell you how to get a thread by name. Once you have your thread object, can you not check the IsAlive property ?

Comment: My confusion is if that method is reliable ? Also thread.name does not exist

Comment: @Rajeshwar: reliable for what? E.g., this property can't detect, if the thread is hanging somewhere in native code, or executing some infinite loop in managed.

Comment: You want to avoid the use of isAlive property?

Comment: No. I wanted to know if that code is valid. Because I cant seem to access the name property of the thread. The answer to that post used the name property i.e thread.name. But I cant find that property.

Comment: To answer your question directly, No it is not helpful because the Process.Threads returns a collection of ProcessThread objects and not Thread objects. To answer your question of how to do it, i still dont know, research in progress.

Comment: It seems like a bad design decision. You should not chek thread IsAlive property to check is it alive or not.